# Angular: How to read ViewChild of a dynamically loaded component

Tags: angular, viewchild

I have a component which has view child like this

```
@ViewChild('overView') content: ElementRef;
```

I am loading this component dynamically like this

```
var overviewComponent = this.vcr.createComponent(OverviewComponent);
var content = overviewComponent.instance.content;
var nativeElement = content.nativeElement;
```

But I am getting `content` as `undefined`.

I want to read the `nativeElement` of the `content`

Is there any way to read it?

I even tried this but it didn't help

```
@ViewChild('overView', {read: ViewContainerRef}) content: ElementRef;
```

Comment: Probably because AfterViewInit didn't complete yet. You could try wrapping the 2 last lines inside a `setTimeout`

Comment: @Pieterjan - But how would I know for how long I should wait? Is there any way to check if the content is loaded or AfterViewInit is completed?

Answer (score 1):

Making the content static like this worked

```
@ViewChild('overView', {static: true}) content: ElementRef;
```